winui 3 mediacapture camera mode sharedreadonly not sharing the camera stream
we have build an application on winui3. using MediaCapture we are fetching the camera stream. we are enabled SharingMode  as "SharedReadOnly" we expect other applications like teams can access the same stream. It was working fine.  No we are facing issue like teams grabbing the camera in exclusive mode.
  var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
    {
        SourceGroup = mediaFrameGroup,
        SharingMode = MediaCaptureSharingMode.SharedReadOnly
        StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video,
        MemoryPreference = MediaCaptureMemoryPreference.Cpu,
        MediaCategory = MediaCategory.Communications
    };

How can use shareReadOnly?
Teams accessing camera feed as exclusive mode it should not happen.
